# jquery closest() parent and parent before

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clear the input fields of the closest parent AND the one above. If you run the below code, it clears the closest three fields, but not all six.

Is anyone able to point out what I need to add to my "remove" function to achieve this?

Thanks

```js
$('.hiddenDV').hide();
$(".add-another").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.row').nextAll('.hiddenDV:lt(2)').slideDown();
});
$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.row').hide().prev('.hiddenDV').slideUp();
  $(this).closest(".hiddenDV").find('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  line-break: normal;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  background-position: 7px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEemployerTXB">Employer:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEnatureTXB">Nature of business:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEpostheldTXB">Post held:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEsalaryonleavingTXB">Salary on leaving:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEdateemployedTXB">From:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEleavingdateTXB">To:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnEMPAdd1" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
  </div>


  <div id="DV_EMP1" class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEemployerTXB2">Employer:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEnatureTXB2">Nature of business:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEpostheldTXB2">Post held:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="DV_EMP2" class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEsalaryonleavingTXB2">Salary on leaving:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEdateemployedTXB2">From:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEleavingdateTXB2">To:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnEMPAdd2" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    <input type="button" id="btnEMPDel2" class="btn btn-default extra-margin remove" value="-" />
  </div>

  <div id="DV_EMP3" class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEemployerTXB3">Employer:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEnatureTXB3">Nature of business:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEpostheldTXB3">Post held:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="DV_EMP4" class="row hiddenDV">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEsalaryonleavingTXB3">Salary on leaving:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEdateemployedTXB3">From:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="OEleavingdateTXB3">To:</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnEMPAdd3" class="btn btn-default extra-margin add-another" value="+" />
    <input type="button" id="btnEMPDel3" class="btn btn-default extra-margin remove" value="-" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
$('.hiddenDV').hide();
$(".add-another").click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.row').nextAll('.hiddenDV:lt(2)').slideDown();
});
$(".remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.row').hide().prev('.hiddenDV').slideUp();
  $(this).closest(".hiddenDV").find('input[type="text"]').val('');
  $(this).closest(".hiddenDV").prev(".hiddenDV").find('input[type="text"]').val('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for. I thought I would have tried something like this, guess not. Thanks! :)

Comment: Great.. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

First, use:

```
$(".remove").on('click',function() {

});
```

Second, when You are in:

```
$(".remove").on('click',function(){  

});
```

$(this) - looking for elements in ".remove" class but in Your code I do not see ".remove" class that is parent of divs that You are looking for.

Try to add every "row" a second class like "row row-1" and then:

```
$(".remove").on('click',function(){  
   $('.row.row-1').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      $(this).val('');
   });
});
```